# excel chart dynamic range based on values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I'm trying to create a chart that auto updates itself from a data provided. The range of the chart is always `fixed/locked`. The issue I'm facing is that when a value for a certain month is 0, I want it to skip to the last non-zero month . Meaning the ranges selected forming the chart should exclude the month with the value zero. Which in most cases is the top month.

The image below should clear it up. 
[image]

Is there a way to have the chart range  be ***dynamic based on certain values***?

Comment: It may, but I have 20 other columns that some have December data and some that don't. So there's still a lot of manual work. A workaround might help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dummy column that automagically contains the X (horizontal axis) value (i.e., the date for the row) if the (Y) value is non-zero, and `#N/A` if the value is zero, as shown below.  Then chart the dummy column.

[image: spreadsheet with data from the questionand D1 =IF(B1<>0, A1, #N/A]

Note: this will give you errors saying “A formula in this worksheet contains one or more invalid references” just because you have a formula that evaluates to `#N/A`. 
Ignore the errors.

Hmm. If (as you state in your comment) you have other columns with Y values that go against the same X (month) values, you will need a dummy column for each real column. 
I suggest that you create them on a different worksheet. 
That also solves the problem of hiding the dummy columns without Hiding them
(because, if you Hide them, that messes up the chart).

Comment: this is a clever workaround. I'm playing with it and getting closer. This method solves one part. Is there a way to totally hide/not show up the #N/A cells. That way I can have a chart range fixed on say the top 12 cells and won't have to redraw the range in the future if say January becomes #N/A.

Comment: @andrew: Excuse me, I have cobwebs in my head today.  I don’t understand your question.  Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Sure Scott. Thanks a lot btw. A picture may speak a thousand words. Take a loot at this: top part is current, bottom is desired: http://i.imgur.com/yLyTg.png Thanks again.

Comment: @andrew: Oh, I understand.  The only thing that comes to mind immediately is a bit of a kludge: As shown in my answer, define `D1` to be `=IF(B1<>0, A1, #N/A)` and drag (fill) it down to `D12`.  Then define `D13` to be `=IF(B1=0, A13, #N/A)` and drag (fill) it down to `D24`.  Then define the chart to be based on all 24 rows.  (If you can guarantee that you will have only one zero, then just define `D13` (don’t drag/fill) and define the chart to be based on the first 13 rows.)